# CALayer inverted mask reveal animation

Tags: ios, swift3, core-animation

I am struggling with the Animation of the inverted CALayer mask. The aim is:
1. To create a circle mask (yellow circle in this example) where the content of the background view (yellow background color) is visible through the mask.
2. To animate the circle mask from zero diameter to a desired diameter (revealing effect)

**Initial state:**
[image: Initial state]

**Last state:**
[image: Last state]

Please note: Both views content is a real content with images and controls, not just a filled background color.

The first part is done. With the second part (Animation) there is an issue.
The sample code for the first part is as follows:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        view.backgroundColor = .yellow

        let childView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 1024.0, height: 768.0))
        childView.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(childView)

        let maskRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), size: CGSize(width: 200.0, height: 200.0))
        addInvertedMask(toView: childView, withinRect: maskRect)
}

    fileprivate func addInvertedMask(toView view: UIView, withinRect rect: CGRect) {
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        let path = UIBezierPath()

        // Invert Mask
        let rectFullscreenPath = UIBezierPath(rect: view.bounds)
        path.append(rectFullscreenPath)
        maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd

        let circleMaskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: rect.size.width/2)
        path.append(circleMaskPath)

        maskLayer.path = path.cgPath

        view.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    }
}
```

Probably I am on the wrong way, so the animation here is impossible. However I did not find any solution to create the inverted mask other way.

I would appreciate your help!

**UPDATE**

After some research I decided to implement a totally another approach:

- I make a screenshot of the UIView that I later use as a mask (See the yellow circle). See the function below:

  ```
  fileprivate func makeMapScreenshot(view: UIView) -> UIImage? {
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, true, 0)
      view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
      let snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

      return snapshot
  }
  ```
- Than I crop the screenshot to the size of my mask (yellow circle) with the following extension/function:

  ```
  extension UIImage {
      func cropping(to rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, self.scale)

          self.draw(in: CGRect(x: -rect.origin.x, y: -rect.origin.y, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height))

          let croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
          UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

          return croppedImage
      }
  }
  ```

As last step I create on a CALayer of the yellow circle view a radius with clipped bounds. Before it I put of course the UIImage into the UIImageView object:

```
    let yellowCircleImageView = UIImageView(image: mapSnapshotImageCropped)
    yellowCircleImageView.layer.cornerRadius = yellowCircleImageView.frame.size.width / 2
    yellowCircleImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Now it is possible to position/resize and animate the yellow circle UImageView.

Comment: Take a look at this article. It includes your "expanding circle reveal" task - and a bit more... you should be able to get where you want to go. https://www.raywenderlich.com/94302/implement-circular-image-loader-animation-cashapelayer

Comment: Thank you @DonMag. However I could not get a solution from this RW Article. I decided to take another approach. See my answer.